# Spring boot JAR as windows service AND external application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, windows-services, tomcat9

I packaged my spring boot application into a jar and I made it as a web service via apache tomcat 9 with a .bat file.

on the other hand the externalization of application-prod.yml does not work and the .yml file is ignored in the same path as the jar.

how can I do it please

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works with the command line by launching java -jar example.jar and placing the property file in the mm folder than the jar but when we create a windows service with the tomcat9 tool (serviceInstall.bat ) and we make the jar a windows service,
the application-prod.yml file is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

use packaging tools to package,such as maven.
if you use maven,you should config packaging plugins

Comment: Hello, thanks but I don't have a packaging problem.
my question is how to externalize application-prod.yml file when we create the jar as a windows service with the tomcat9 tool (serviceInstall.bat).

Comment: What you mean is to separate the prd.yml configuration and let the application load and read it every time you start the service. If that means, Spring Boot allows you to externalize the configuration. Spring Boot uses a very special PropertySource command, which is designed to allow values to be rewritten wisely. The properties are considered in the following order: 1. Java system properties, 2. OS environment variables.

Comment: yes it's work for me putting the yml in the same jar folder and run java -jar myapp.jar but create a windows service with service.bat script and tomcat9 it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you may check the [official document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.1/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-files), and as your `.yml` file is already in the same path as the jar file, you may try this :

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/your/yaml
```

Comment: You also need to add the `file:` prefix in the location as follows `java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=file:///some/path/application.yml`